# MySQL server upgrade, how to adapt variables?

Tags: mysql, configuration, memory, my.cnf, cpu

I am about to upgrade my MySQL server because I have currently used it mainly with a couple of people in the development stage. Before we launch, however, we would like more capacity to avoid the server crashing. I currently run on a Ubuntu system with 2 GB of RAM, 2 vCPU's, 60 GB disk and 3 TB of monthly transfer.

My variables are set to:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_io_capacity      = 1900
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT
key_buffer_size         = 10M
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 100
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
query_cache_limit       = 10M
query_cache_size        = 0
slow_query_log          = 1
slow_query_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time         = 2
wait_timeout            = 300
interactive_timeout     = 300
```

I am about to ugprade my server to 8 GB RAM, 4 vCPU's, 160 GB of disk space and 5 TB of monthly transfer. The size of my table is currently 1.3 MB, but this will of course increase as soon as more users become active. How much this will increase and how fast, I can not really say for sure.

So I am now trying to figure out how I should change my variables to get the best performance. I know I should allocate my memory correctly, and these settings work fine for the setup I currently have, but if I need to change anything for the upgraded system, I would really appreciate some insights.

Cheers!

Comment: SSD?  Or not?...

Comment: Yes, ssd disk. I’m hosting on DigitalOcean as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset size is only 1,3MB, then buffer_pool_size = 256M gives you a lot of  growing room.

If HDD, change `innodb_io_capacity` back to the default of 200.

The slowlog (which you have already turned on) will provide info on what to fix if you have performance problems.

Has the server crashed?  If so, let's see details on that.

Do you have other apps crammed into the tiny 2GB of RAM?  Changing to 8GB is likely to help with *that*.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback! It’s definitely SSD disk and the server is dedicated for the MySQL database. Other processes are just the regular Ubuntu stuff on there. I have a separate droplet/server for my node.js application (which has lower specs, but I figured http requests won’t cost me as much memory or cpu power) and I have a dedicated object spaces solution from DigitalOcean for my image/video files. Would 1900 create a problem on io capacity?

Comment: Also, server hadn’t crashed with these configurations. Used to run on 1 GB ram, 1 vCPU and default MySQL my.cnf settings, crashed once and had the configuration adapted since then.

Comment: Now when we are launching, I expect a couple hundred to thousand new users, so I’m kind of afraid the server might crash in that scenario, hence why I want to upgrade so we are in the safe.

Comment: @PennyWise - 1900 is probably fine for SSD.  How many Queries per second when you get the thousand users?

Comment: Currently, with 10 users and server online for 10 hours (restarted this morning): **Threads: 3  Questions: 5868  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 1315  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 1075  Queries per second avg: 0.172** - I guess this will increase significantly but not hit anything crazy. Can I predict this somehow?

Comment: @PennyWise - Hard to predict.  I don't think I have ever seen a production system with only 0.172 qps.  90% of servers run with more than 1qps.

Comment: Well, with only 10 users, isn’t it normal? If no one opens the application for, say, an hour, then there wouldnNt be any queries performed at this stage. There will be a couple of cronjobs in the future, but apart from that, I guess it makes sense, no?

Comment: @PennyWise - Sure, 10 users doing very little; that is fine.  Based on the limited information available, growing to 1000 users with similar activity will probably still be fine.  17qps is only about the 30th percentile.  As I said, the slowlog will be your friend _if_ you do hit performance problems.

Comment: Sounds great. Do you think it would be able to handle this on the current 2 GB RAM system? I’ll upgrade anyway - just in case, can always downgrade later. We’ll keep a close look on slowlog and errorlog, so that should give us some insights indeed. So far I’ve indexed most of what’s needed (where clauses and joins), so that should help too.

Comment: So I just upgraded to 8 GB RAM, 4 vCPU's and 160 GB SSD. I have not edited anything to my.cnf so it is still as mentioned in OP. However, am I now not losing a lot of RAM space, as the buffer pool is set to only 256 MB? Will the upgrade have any effect on my database server or is it just a waste of money (which can be useful later, when growing)?

Comment: @PennyWise - Waste of memory until you increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size to, say, 5500M.  On the other hand, I would have expected the provider to increase that.

Comment: I'm configuring everything myself at the moment, at least until I can afford some third party help. So I always thought I should set the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70-80% of available RAM, as a rule of thumb, but considering your first answer on this post, I guess there is a better way to calculate it based on the size of the dataset, correct?

Comment: @PennyWise - The smaller of the two.  But using the % allows for growth.